# Analytical solution of system of non-linear equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

I need to **analytically** solve this system of non-linear equations:
\begin{cases}
x + (y-1)^2 + 2z^2 = 10 \\
x^2 + y^2 + 3z = 28 \\
2x + y + z = 12
\end{cases}
I solve this system numerically with [Gradient Descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent) method and with different initial approximations obtained the following solutions:
\begin{array}{c|lll}
\text{1} & x = 4 & y = 3 & z = 1 \\ \hline
\text{2} & x \approx 4.75151 & y \approx 0.94466 & z \approx 1.62509
\end{array}
I tested the solutions with different software, such as Wolfram and Python libraries, and they gave about the same result.

But no matter how I try to solve a seemingly simple system analytically, I can't do it, because the solutions are too complicated. Perhaps I am doing something wrong, and I would be glad to get even if not a solution, at least tips on how to find it.

Thanks!

Comment: @gpmath, thank you for answer! This solution seemed strange to me and I decided to double-check the system. I made a small mistake by forgetting the degree in first equation, sorry.

Comment: Your solution 2 is wrong, correct is $\{x\to 4.715115361323142,y\to 0.9446809049263751,z\to 1.625088372427342\}$

Comment: Exact form for $x\approx 4.715115361323142$:  https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1334%2F267+-+38447%2F267+%282%2F%28-9080939+%2B+173283+sqrt%2810317%29%29%29%5E%281%2F3%29+%2B+1%2F267+%281%2F2+%28-9080939+%2B+173283+sqrt%2810317%29%29%29%5E%281%2F3%29&assumption=%22ClashPrefs%22+-%3E+%7B%22Math%22%7D

Comment: @gpmath Yes, y has accuracy problems, thanks for the note, but this is more about the my implementation of the numerical method of solving the system, not about an analytical solution

Comment: @Chonk The exact analytic solution is given in my link above. It is the root of cubic polynomial with integer coefficients

Comment: For solution of a system of polynomial equations: see "resultant" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant#Application_to_polynomial_systems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(3)$ gives $z=-2 x-y+12$

$3 \times (2)-(1)$ gives $y=\frac{-5 x^2+77 x-255}{8 x-41}$

Plug in $(1)$ to obtain
$$\frac{3 (x-4) \left(89 x^3-1334 x^2+6809 x-11777\right)}{(8   x-41)^2}=0$$

Solbing the cubic equation using the hyperbolic solution for only one real root gives
$$x=\frac{2}{267} \left(667-\sqrt{38447} \sinh \left(\frac{1}{3} \sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{9080939}{76894
   \sqrt{38447}}\right)\right)\right)$$ which is $$4.7151153613231415366265466208961077638519627948872$$

Comment: Thank you very much, it was very helpful in finding an analytical solution!